# Replacing all "E" characters in file to "Z" and all "Z" characters to "E"

Tags: javascript

i want to replace all "E" characters in file to "Z" and all "Z" characters to "E", the problem is once i replace one of them, i cant replace the other, because then all the characters are e/z

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a function and an object with the replacments.

```js
var string = 'EaEbZcZdZ';

string = string.replace(/[EZ]/g, s => ({ E: 'Z', Z: 'E' }[s]));
console.log(string);
```

Answer (score 4):

Change all "E" to an unused character in the document, e.g. "$". Change "Z" to "E" and then "$" to "Z".

Answer (score 1):

Replace all E to an unused character (like ¬), then change all Z to E, and finally change all ¬ to Z.